# Microsoft Dynamics Online: adding "Add new Opportunity" (related to record) link to the form

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I am customizing Accounts form layout. I would like to add "Add new Opportunity" hyperlink to the form. The opportunity should be related to the record.

What I've done:

- I converted the text box to hyperlink. I have a working hyperlink.
- I can point my hyperlink to "Add new Opportunity" page, as described here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc150850.aspx

But the opportunity is not related to the particular Account record.

What I need to do:

- I need to address my link to "Add new Opportunity", but **related** to the particular Account record.

Any advices? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you must obtain full URL of form for creation of new opportunity.
For my contact I have:

> https://contoso.crm4.dynamics.com/main.aspx?etc=3&extraqs=%3f_CreateFromId%3d%257b**1368FD64-C21A-E311-8AC9-3C4A92DBCCDF**%257d%26_CreateFromType%3d2%26etc%3d3%26pagemode%3diframe%26preloadcache%3d1380105302598&pagetype=entityrecord

the bolted GUID is the id of record you want to be related to opportunity.
So you need to investigate your URL and place Account Id in correct place

Comment: Thank you. I got entity id by using JavaScript: Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId()